Expo-Camera React Native problem. Error: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
how are you? Well, I have a problem with my App in React Native, I use an Expo-Camera documentation, but it is not working. The errors are:

(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.
I use the code of documentation, but it is not working, can I help, please? Thank you.
Amm PD: The CameraType is not recognized when called on line 6

import { CameraView, CameraType, useCameraPermissions } from 'expo-camera';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    const [facing, setFacing] = useState < CameraType > ('back');
    const [permission, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();

    if (!permission) {
        // Camera permissions are still loading.
        return <View />;
    }

    if (!permission.granted) {
        // Camera permissions are not granted yet.
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.message}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
                <Button onPress={requestPermission} title="grant permission" />
            </View>
        );
    }

    function toggleCameraFacing() {
        setFacing(current => (current === 'back' ? 'front' : 'back'));
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <CameraView style={styles.camera} facing={facing}>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={toggleCameraFacing}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Flip Camera</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </CameraView>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    message: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingBottom: 10,
    },
    camera: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        margin: 64,
    },
    button: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
    },
});```


Well, I'm trying different Expo-Camera codes and helping myself with AI, but the AI ​​doesn't work, it stays in a loop with the same errors.

